# Oracle : Global temporary tables

Tags: performance, oracle

In my application, we have multilple global temporary tables (5-6) in an oracle function. We have indexes on the temporary tables as these can hold significant amount of data. This function is called by different users at the same time (about 30 instances). After first few calls - we are seeing timeout issues - after deleting stats on these tmp table application perform fine.

I did some research on google and it seems that global temp tables shares the stats:
http://blog.go-faster.co.uk/2009/10/global-temporary-tables-shared.html

I like to know what could be the solution for this scenario, other than dropping indexes.

Comment: Are you gathering statistics during the 30 simultaneous calls? Or are things OK after you delete the stats, until they are next gathered on a schedule? What exact issues and errors do you get?

Comment: A good idea for GTTs would be to delete stats and lock it.

Comment: We are creating global temporary table and indexes prior to the first run of the function. In the function, temp tables will get populated and then various data processing steps. Finally before the function return, I am truncating all the temp tables.  Things are ok once we clean the stats until next stats is gathered on schedule (saturdays) - we see these issues on mondays.  Also It was never an issue for a year and as client increased number of execution - this issues started.  Do you think droping indexes on temp or any other setting will fix this one?

Comment: Exact error is slowness - workflow which used to take 20 mins will run for 2 + hrs.

Comment: Annjawn : Based on your comment, do you think dropping indexes will be better (as you are suggesting to drop stats - which makes them unusable anyways)? Can you please explain more or point me to some documentation about "dropping stats and lock".

Comment: @AmitArora - Dropping stats doesn't make indexes unusable.  It just causes the optimizer to use dynamic sampling to gather stats at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Once we delete the stats - how can we lock it then, I believe by locking it will not re-analyzed on next schedule?